# C++ void function exercise error

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I am currently learning void functions.
I am trying to write a function that squares a number, using a void function. Here is my code.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void square(int);

int main()
{
int x = 0;
cout << "Please enter a number. It will be squared.";
cin >> x;
cout << x << 't' << square(x);
}

void square(int x)
{
int y = x*x;
cout << y;
}
```

The error the IDE gives me is:

```
 no match for 'operator<<' (operand types that are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' 
and 'void')
```

Speaking from experience, many people will ask about the header file `std_lib_facilities.h`, that is not the problem. I am able to say that because I did many exercises using this header file and they all worked.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You're trying to print the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 3):

A void function cannot directly return a value.  Most people would use a non-void function to implement squaring, like this:

```
int square(int x)
{
  return x * x;
}
```

I see that your `square` function writes the squared value to `std::cout` itself.  That is odd, but if you really want to do it that way, you should replace the last line of the `main` function with:

```
cout << x << 't';
square(x);
```

You cannot typically use the result of a void function in an expression, which is the problem with your original code.

Answer (score 0):

`square()` is void - i.e. it does not return anything.

`cout << x << 't' << square(x);` tries to print the return value of `square()` (which we've already said doesn't exist). This makes no sense so the compiler complains.

What you want to do is make `square` return an int rather than print it.

```
int square(int x)
{
    return  x*x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess changing the return type will make the error vanish. The compiler error is because of no overloaded version of << which takes in void as a parameter,as your function is (erroneously) telling the compiler.