# C++ - Write void function value to file

Tags: c++

I have void c++ function which output the numbers and whenever I call the function it shows all numbers but when i try to write those numbers to file it gives me an error

I have already tried this

```
void average(int num)
{
num = 2;
cout << num;
}

 int main() {

        int num;
        average(num);

        ofstream file("tests.txt");
        file<< average(num); // on file it should write 2
 }
```

It gives an error "error: no match for 'operator<<'"

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `average` function returns?

Comment: Why does the function return `void` rather than the values?

Comment: my void function displays numbers like (1,2,3,4)

Comment: It could help to expose the code of `average()`. Please [edit] your question to add relevant info. Btw. if `average()` has return type `void`, you cannot use it in a file stream. There is no `operator<<()` which takes `void` as 2nd arg. (That's impossible.)

Comment: You're question is missing a lot of information. What is `num`? How's `average()` implemented? Also it might else what platform you're running on, Windows, Linux or whatever.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza There is no `operator<<()` which takes `void` as 2nd arg. (That's impossible ... on any platform.) ;-)

Comment: void average(int num)
{
    num = 2;
    cout << num;
}

int main() {

            int num;
            average(num);

            ofstream file("tests.txt");
            file<< average(num);

}

Comment: @Scheff I know, thanks. I want to know the platform to help OP solve the problem.

Comment: If you add the necessary `#include`s you just made a [mcve]. Regarding your function, you should consider to change the return type (to e.g. `int` or `double`) and return the average value. Then, you can use it in the stream as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ void function exercise error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380907/c-void-function-exercise-error)

Answer (score 2):

Your function "average" can't be void, it has to return something for example a float:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

float average( float x, float y ){
    return  (x+y)/2;
}


int main(){
    ofstream file;
    file.open ("file.txt");
    file << average(3,4) << endl;
}
```

More about << operator:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `average` function you are printing the values using std::cout, and trying to catch them outside in the file, using the `operator<<`. It doesn't work this way. If you want to print those values to the file, you can do this in some ways. For example, one of them:

Return non-void value from your `average` function. Return the values that you want to print, for example, if you want to print some integers, you can return an array or a vector from your function, that includes the values you want to print, and then iterate over them and print the into the file (or just write them).

For example:

```
std::vector<int> average() {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.emplace_back(1);
    return numbers;
}
```

And to print values to the file:

```
std::ofstream file ("tests.txt");

std::vector<int> vec = average(3);

file.write((char*)vec.data(), vec.size());
```

But in your case, it seems like you have to calculate an average of some numbers, so in your function's params, you can receive a vector, and calculate their average:

```
double average(const std::vector<double> &numbers) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (auto &num : numbers) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return sum / numbers.size();
}
```

And then print it to the file:

```
std::ofstream file ("tests.txt");

file << average({1, 2.34, 4}) << std::endl;
```

### Another way of thinking..

However, if you want to leave the function as it returns void, you can pass the file as a parameter to the function (**Not recommended for generic code reason**):

```
void average(const std::vector<double> &numbers, std::ofstream &output_file) {
    double sum = 0;
    double avg;
    for (auto &num : numbers) {
        sum += num;
    }
    avg = sum / numbers.size();
    output_file << avg;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
std::ofstream file("tests.txt");
average({1, 2.34, 4}, file);
file << std::endl;
```